# assign object in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, assign

i'm trying to assign object in array. for example:

```
var catties = [];

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  catties[i].name = "cat" + i;
}

var Str = "";

for (var j=0; j<catties.length; j++){
  Str = Str + catties[j].name + "\n";
}
alert(Str);
```

so, i want the output gonna be like:
cat1
cat2
cat3
etc

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: its error if write the code like that

Comment: People will generally help you faster if you post the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var catties = [];

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var temp={};
  temp.name = "cat" + i;
  catties.push(temp);
}

var Str = "";

for (var j=0; j<catties.length; j++){
  Str = Str + catties[j].name + "\n";
}
alert(Str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this block:

```
  for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
    catties[i].name = "cat" + i;
  }
```

You're assigning values to indices of the array that don't exist yet.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var cat = { name: "cat" + i };
  catties.push(cat);
}
```

or

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var cat = { name: "cat" + i };
  catties[i] = cat;
}
```

This appends the "cat" variable to the end of the array.

Comment: Not `.name` isn't defined (it wouldn't matter, we assign to it), but `catties[i]`. You don't need to use `push` btw, assigning to `catties[i]` would be fine as well.

Comment: You're correct; been switching between Java and JS too much today.  Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Fiddle that does what you need. "names" object is not defined:

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/94tVw/

```
var catties = [];

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
    catties.push({'name': 'cat' + i});
}

var Str = "";

for (var j=0; j<catties.length; j++){
  Str = Str + catties[j].name + "\n";
}
alert(Str);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/funeq/1/edit)**

If you want to push objects inside array, you need to construct an object first and then you can push it.

As per your code, you have only pushed the value.

So use this :

```
var catties = [];

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  var tempObject = {};
  tempObject.name = "cat" + i;
  catties.push(tempObject);
}

var Str = "";

for (var j=0; j<catties.length; j++){
  Str = Str + catties[j].name + "\n";
}
alert(Str);
```